# Biblatex electronic source

Tags: biblatex

This electronic source

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[backend = biber, style=authoryear, uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{ref.bib} 

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib} 

@Electronic{Friston2,
  author    = {K. J. Friston},
  year      = {2011}
  url       = {http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/course/video/},
  timestamp = {2017.04.24}
  }

\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

\textcite{Friston2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

appears like this in the bibliography: K. J. Friston (2011). Introduction to SPM. http://...
but it should be like: Friston, K. J. (2011). Introduction to SPM. http://...

And when I textcite, it's like this: K. J. Friston, (2011) instead of: Friston (2011)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a minimal example. The proper format for names in the `.bib` file  is `Friston, K. J.` not `K. J. Friston`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. Could there be another reason?

Comment: If I compile your example (with a comma after the year in the `.bib` file) I get the output you want.  Did you delete your `.aux` files and run `biber` again?

Answer (score 3):

The proper format for names in the `.bib` file is:

```
LastName, FirstName and LastName, I. I.
```

For a single name you can get away with `FirstName LastName` but it's better not to.

Here's your example (I added a comma after the year in the `.bib` file.)

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[style=authoryear, uniquename=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib} 

@Electronic{Friston2,
  author    = {Friston, K. J. },
  year      = {2011},
  url       = {http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/course/video/},
  timestamp = {2017.04.24}
  }
\end{filecontents} 

\begin{document}

\textcite{Friston2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The source is correctly displayed in the bibliography now, but \textcite still adds a comma: Friston, (2011) This reference appears in a figure's caption in footnote size, but \footcite gives me a superscripted 1.

Comment: @Cathy Since my example doesn't show the problem, can you edit your minimal document to reproduce it.  There must be something else going on. Is the `.bib` item exactly the same as in my example?

Comment: @Cathy The spurious comma in `\textcite` is a problem with an older version of `biblatex`. This has been fixed a few versions ago. In the current 3.7 there is no comma any more.

Comment: Thanks, I updated `biblatex` and `biber` and the comma disappeared. I'm just wondering why it was there all of a sudden. I had a similar (sudden) problem with the spacing between volume and number.

Comment: @cathy The simple answer is 'bugs happen' :) `biblatex` is a complex piece of software, and as with all software, changes in one area can sometimes have unintended consequences in another.